# Quarkus 2.0 dev mode running tests with kafka dependency

Tags: quarkus, redpanda

I'm trying to run tests in quarkus:dev mode with some kafka tests.

The problem is that the quarkus:dev mode test runner can't start the redpanda kafka container. Is that a know problem or is that currently not possible to do?

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please [include in your question post everything needed to invite useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): How does `quarkus:dev mode test runner can't start the redpanda kafka container` manifest?

Answer (score 0):

@kai what logs can you post on the redpanda side? you can try to pin the image to say `vectorized.io/redpanda:v21.8.1`  or smth like that in case you had a cached old image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29778459)

Comment: @procrastinator that's fine. but I am trying to help. I wrote the code for redpanda as the initial author, so i'd say i'm an expert in that subject. To help, i'd need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `quarkus.kafka.devservices.enabled` property is set to `true`.